# Android two sounds when pressing button

Tags: android, button, audio

I am trying to use two sounds when I button is pushed: one sound when the button is pressed and another when the button is release. How can I accomplish this?

I currently play a sound when a button is clicked with this:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Test.this, R.raw.mysound);   
            mp.start();
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }

            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: You will need to handle `onTouch` yourself in order to detect when the button is released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an `OnTouchListener`:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
    int action = ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // Play "click" sound
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        // Play "unclick" sound
    }
}
```

You can attach that to an `OnTouchListener` using `setOnTouchListener()` the same way you've demonstrated with the `OnClickListener` you have already.